# How to import js file and reference in Ionic2 project whit TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I try to import a js file in my ionic2 project to encript data, but i get this error when i run:

```
TypeScript error: /app/service/Util.service.ts(49,23): Error TS2663: Cannot find name 'RSAKey'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.RSAKey'?
```

TypeScript error: /app/service/Util.service.ts(52,16): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'hex2b64'.

I copy the library in a folder and i reference in index.html, this works in Angular v1.

I read in the ionic2 documentation and i seed that i need to instal whit npm, buy i dont know how do this.
Anny sugestion??
Thanks!!:

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can work with this.

One you can hack it and slap typescript in the face by doing this

```
(<any>window).RSAKey
```

Or you can write a proper typing for your library something like this

```
interface IRSAKey{
  dostuff(): Promise<IRSAKeyResult>;
  hex2b64:string;
}

interface IRSAKeyResult{

}

declare var RSAKey: IRSAKey;
```

After this import your interface and you can use RSAKey freely